# Always join Skype for Business meetings with desktop client

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype-for-business

Our organization uses Skype for Business in a way so that links to meetings have the following form

```
https://lync.co.<tld-of-company>/meet/<user-id>/<identifier>
```

When clicking on this link, a page is displayed that asks me with which client I want to join the conference, either the "Skype Meetings App (web)" or the "Skype for Business (desktop)" client.

[image: Skype for business client selection page]

This dialog is annoying because **I always want to join with the desktop client**. Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to automatically open the desktop client with the following Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Auto-redirect to Skype for Business desktop client
// @version  1
// @grant    none
// @include  https://lync.co.<your-domain-here>/*
// ==/UserScript==

window.onload = function() {
  var matches = window.location.href.match(/^https:\/\/[^/]*\/meet\/([^/]*)\/([^/?]*)/);
  if (matches) {
    var emailDomain = "@<your-domain-here>"
    var target = "conf:sip:" + matches[1] + emailDomain + ";gruu;opaque=app:conf:focus:id:" + matches[2] + "%3Frequired-media=audio"
    console.log("Redirecting to " + target)
    window.location = target
  }
}
```

It computes the `conf:` URI from the client selection URL and opens it.

Note that the two occurrences of `<your-domain-here>` needs to be replaced by the appropriate corporate domains.